# Can we specifically annotate a line within given range or ask line annotator to run for n times post this keyword in Ruta?

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, uima, ruta

```
BLOCK(structure) Line{}{
    Line{-> TestLine};
}
```

This code will annotate all lines with `TestLine`. Is this possible to annotate `first 10 lines` or say `n number of lines`? Or Can we ask it to stop further annotation if it encounters any specific `keyword` or start annotation once `keyword` is encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to store the number of times you want to match and then annotate based on that. Please refer to documentation, section [variables](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.language.declarations.variable).

As simple example to annotate the first 4 lines would be:

```
DECLARE TestLine;

INT counter;
Line{counter<4 -> TestLine, counter = counter+1};
```

Comment: is it possible to have start condition or end condition while iterating through lines? for eg start-condition : `Line{CONTAINS(X)}` and end condition : `Line{CONTAINS(Y)}`

Comment: Sure. `Line{CONTAINS(Keyword), counter<4 -> TestLine, counter = counter+1};` will only annotate the lines which contain your keyword.

Comment: Thanks but I want to annotate 4 lines present after this keyword not lines containing this keyword. If I just want to annotate lines containing keyword I can do this `Line{CONTAINS(TestKeyword)} -> {Line{->TestLine};};`.  `counter` variable will come handy only when I want to annotate less number of lines than actually present.

Comment: Try this: `Line{CONTAINS(TestKeyword)} # @Line{-CONTAINS(TestKeyword), -PARTOF(TestLine), counter<4 -> TestLine, counter = counter+1};`. The `@` is used to set the anchor element (i.e. where to start the matching).

Comment: thanks, it works . Similar to `@` do we have any element where we could mark end the matching. Consider Use Case where u want to annotate all lines present between two keywords. `@` will be used to start but how to end match?

Comment: The end of the matching window can be marked with another `EndIndicator`. For example: `Line{CONTAINS(TestKeyword)} # @Line{-CONTAINS(TestKeyword), -PARTOF(TestLine), counter<4 -> TestLine, counter = counter+1} # EndIndicator;`. This will not allow the line matching to go over your indicator.